# Sound Synthesis with F#

Tags: f#

How to generate sounds in F# with mac ? I mean build the songs using different kinds of waves (sin, saw, etc.) and their options (chords, envelopes, basic filters, etc.)

Comment: I've been trying to find a good library for this as well. I haven't found one that's cross-platform, though.

Answer (score 6):

You can use FYampaSynth ([Github](https://github.com/brianberns/FYampaSynth), [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FYampaSynth/)) to do this if you're on Windows. Here's a short example:

```ml
use engine = new AudioEngine()
Synth.oscSine 440.0   // A above middle C
    >>^ (*) 0.05      // reduce volume
    |> Synth
    |> engine.AddInput
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library.